# Private APIs used in my project - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, iphone-privateapi

I need to check if i have used any `private API`s in my application. Most of the answers posted in SO suggest to use the tool [AppScanner](http://www.chimpstudios.com/appscanner/), to find out.

But when i add the `.app` file to `AppScanner`, it crashes. So this doesn't work.

1.) Are there any other ways where i could check if my application uses private APIs ?

2.) I am using code from this [tutorial](http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-uiimage-asynchronously/), there are properties declared as Private in this, i am not sure if the libraies used in this project are using Private APIs. Could some one kindly check ?

Comment: you cannot mark properties private, but ivars. But the better approach IMHO is to use class extensions for that, at this doesn't show the properties/ivars in the possible public header files. and ivar private accessibility has nothing to do with apple private apis.

Comment: Also if you are grabbing source code, check if it is a modern one. Grand central dispatch might be the better solution. and that source code has some oddities (a `setDelegate` method instead of a property, also with modern compilers you don't have to define ivars for properties at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `Validate` button at Xcode organizer Archives section; you have to create an app record at itunes-connect to be able to submit an app for validation but you don't have to submit an app to appstore after the validation, an unused app record will be deleted automatically in about 170 days i believe.

[image]

Comment: Where can i find more information about this ? If xCode already provides this functionality then why are so many rejected apps out there ? (Just curious since i am a beginner)

Comment: @shajem More information about app distribution and particularly validation in the article http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html Why are so many apps rejected ? Because they don't care to save the time thinking about the most efficient distribution. The best practice would be to start a validation when you are submitting the same release candidate version to your testers, it doubles your productivity.